pycharm Debugger throws "unknown option --port" when app.run(debug=True)
Using dash/plotly to "webify" a former Qt6 app of mine. Struggling with the stateless approach, depending on the visual debugger in pycharm.
Normally, app.run(debug=True) is used to run the dash app, while debug=True prevents warning messages about "do not try this in production" and the usual web server log entries fill up the python console.
app.run(debug=False) removes the logging the the warning, but in Pycharm-Debug mode (cklicking on the bug instead of the "run" arrow), the app says:

Dash is running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/

Serving Flask app 'app'
Debug mode: on
unknown option --port
usage: C:\Program Files\Python311\python.exe [option] ... [-c cmd | -m mod | file | -] [arg] ...
Try `python -h' for more information.

Process finished with exit code 2

Clicking on the "run" arrow lead to the normal

Dash is running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/

Serving Flask app 'app'
Debug mode: on


as it should be.
Any idea what goes wrong here?

The probable reason for this is that the PyCharm debugger has its own set of options and configurations that it expects when running an application in debug mode. The --port option is likely one of the parameters the debugger is trying to pass to the application, but Dash's app.run() function does not recognize this option.

I updated to the PyCharm Version 2024.2.4 and the error disappeared. Now you can set breakpoints in your Dash/Plotly app.
